# How to update child component If parent state value change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a dashboard in which I am filtering data with search fields. On change of data of state, I want to reload graph component where I have passed state property as data value.

```
const intialState = {
    graphData:  null,
    costCenterList: [],
    costCenterValue: []
};
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = intialState;
    this.handleCostCenterChange = this.handleCostCenterChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleCostCenterChange(event, values){     
    var filtered = this.state.graphData.filter(el => values.includes(el.costCode));
    this.setState({graphData: filtered});
  }

  render() { 
    <Grid item md={2}>
        <div>
          <InputLabel id="costCenterLabel" style= {{textAlign:'left', fontWeight:'bold'}}>Cost Center</InputLabel>
           <FormControl style={{minWidth:'200px', width:'100%'}} variant="outlined" >
              <Autocomplete
                  multiple
                  options={this.state.costCenterList.map((p) => p)}
                  renderInput={params => (
                    <TextField {...params} margin="normal" variant="outlined" fullWidth autoComplete="off" />
                  )}
                  onChange={this.handleCostCenterChange}
              />
           </FormControl>
        </div>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item md={12}>
        <BarGraph graphData={this.state.graphData}/>
      </Grid>
  }

 }
```

Code of BarGraph is as follows:

```
export default class BarGraph extends Component {
  state = {
    dataForChart: {
      datasets: [
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Hours Per Cost Center</h3>
        <Bar ref="chart" data={this.state.dataForChart} options = {this.state.barChartOptions} height={242} width={486}/>
      </div>
    );
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    try {

      let graphData = this.props.graphData;
      let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);

      newState.dataForChart.datasets =[{barPercentage: 1, label:'Hours Per Cost Center ', data : graphData, backgroundColor : oBarColours, borderWidth:2, borderColor:oBarColours}];
      newState.dataForChart.labels = oCostCenterDistinct;

      this.setState(newState);
      } catch (error) {
      console.log("Network error: " + error);
    }
  }

}
```

I want to update  component on change of graphData of state. On change with this.setState its updating value of state but not component with new data.

Can any one please help what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you add code for  BarGraph component?

Comment: If Dashboard is the parent, and the handleCostCenterChange() is the method which sets the graphData state, then the re-render should automatically occur anyway. This would re-render Dashboard, and thus re-render BarGraph - if it isn't doing it the way you want/expect then it's probably inside BarGraph, can we see the code for that?

Comment: I have added code for BarGraph. Please have a look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to respond to prop updates. Factor out your data processing into a utility function that is called when the component mounts, and again on updated to props.

```
export default class BarGraph extends Component {
  state = {
    dataForChart: {
      datasets: []
    }
  };

  setData() {
    try {
      const { graphData } = this.props;
      const newState = { ...this.state };

      newState.dataForChart.datasets = [
        {
          barPercentage: 1,
          label: "Hours Per Cost Center ",
          data: graphData,
          backgroundColor: oBarColours,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: oBarColours
        }
      ];
      newState.dataForChart.labels = oCostCenterDistinct;

      this.setState(newState);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Network error: " + error);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.graphData !== this.props.graphData) {
      this.setData();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Hours Per Cost Center</h3>
        <Bar
          ref="chart"
          data={this.state.dataForChart}
          options={this.state.barChartOptions}
          height={242}
          width={486}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @coader92 did you make some changes to make this work? Because I see some problems.

Comment: In the parent code I see code that only ever filters your data, but never replenishes it, i.e. keeps a pristine source of truth. Your first search may be filtering out results that your second search might return. It may be better to instead store your filter condition in state and do the actual filtering as you pass the prop to the `BarGraph`, i.e. `graphData={this.state.graphData.filter(... }`.

Comment: @SuleymanSah if you care to point out the problems I can update. I just dumped it in an editor and fixed major flagged issues I saw.

Comment: `const newState = graphData.dataForChart.datasets` this cause mutation problems

Comment: @DrewReese  this line `const newState = { ...graphData };` must be updated to `const newState = { ...this.state };`

Comment: @SuleymanSah Right, thanks. It's what I get for working 12 hours getting a release out.